# Nginx Mutual Authentication

Tags: nginx, mutual-authentication

I have a problem with Nginx and Mutual Authentication. My server is configured like below:

```
server {
listen       12443 ssl;
server_name  localhost;

ssl_certificate      certs/cert.crt;
ssl_certificate_key  certs/cert.key;

ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:1m;
ssl_session_timeout  5m;

ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;

ssl_client_certificate certs/ca.crt;
ssl_verify_client on;
ssl_verify_depth 1;

...
```

I want to connect to the server with another instance of Nginx (Nginx as client).

How to configure Nginx-Client to authenticate himself with certificate to server?

Answer (score 1):

Two way SSL using client certificate/key is not supported in nginx.

I have added support for two way/mutual authentication in nginx.

See the patch:

https://github.com/nginx/nginx/pull/7 
http://mailman.nginx.org/pipermail/nginx-devel/2014-August/005817.html

[nginx reverse proxy with two way SSL to weblogic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25348806/nginx-reverse-proxy-with-two-way-ssl-to-weblogic)